# Convert base 64 string into image return nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, uiimage

```swift
let str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: str, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let decodedimage = UIImage.init(data: dataDecoded)
```

`decodedImage` is `nil`

If I put this base 64 string into this [link](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/datauri-to-image.html), I get my required image.

Comment: I would guess the `Data(base64Encoded...` is for a base64 encoded string only. But your `"data:image/jpeg;base64,` is not base64 encoded, it is plaintext, the base64 encoded image comes aftewards. Strip that before building your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the string you pass to `Data(base64Encoded:` is not actually base64encoded, it contains some more plaintext in the front.

You need to remove that and only pass the actual base64 encoded image, like so:

```
let str = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQ..."
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: str)!
let decodedimage = UIImage.init(data: dataDecoded)
```

Alternatively you can programatically split the original data at the `,` and take the second part as the actual data input.

At that point you can remove the `options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters` as well since now there should not be any non-base64 chars left - and if there are you should fix the data instead of the code.

Final note: depending on where you get the data from it might be a good idea to not force-unwrap anything and instead deal with a broken / missing image by e.g. displaying a placeholder image.